# Servlet отправка файла клиенту

Tags: java, servlet, загрузка

Мне нужно реализовать передачу файла с сервера на клиент. Файл выбирается сервером и отправляется клиенту. Использую jsp/servlet. Сколько не искал везде есть информация о том как загрузить на сервер а вот как получить толком нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста!) Может у кого есть готовая реализация или направьте на путь истины и просветления где искать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создаём сервлет и переопределяем метод get
2. Получаем наш необходимый файл как массив байт
3. Выставляем в response необходимые атрибуты.
4. Пишем байты в OutputStream response

   ```
   public class GetReportServlet extends HttpServlet {

       public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
           ServletContext context = getServletContext();
           ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
           byte[] byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
           //данный контент type говорит что будет файл в формате excel
           resp.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
           resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
           out.write(byteArray);
           out.flush();
           out.close();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста, а в данном решении есть какое-то ограничение на размер файла?

Comment: @АндрейСосновский Если честно не знаю, никогда этим вопросом не задавался

Answer (score 0):

Можно восопльзоваться библиотекой [commons-fileupload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/). Можно загружать не только файлы но и передавать какие либо данные.

Пример:

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
factory.setRepository(repository);

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

// Process the uploaded items
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю всех. Я сделал следующую реализацию.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = null;
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        int readBytes = 0;
        while ((readBytes = inputStream.read()) != -1)
            outputStream.write(readBytes);
    }catch (ExportException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```